# Summation of double choose functions

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Are there any identities that deals with a summation like $\sum_{i=0}^{9} {12-i\choose3}{3+i\choose3}$.

Comment: i got 11440 as the searched result

Comment: I want to find a way to evaluate that without a calculator.

Comment: **Hint:** Notice that the general term is a simple polynomial in *i*, and then use [Faulhaber's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a $i$ in $\{0, ..., 9\}$. You can say : 
$${12 - i \choose 3}{3 + i \choose 3} = \frac{(12-i)!}{3!(9-i)!}\frac{(3+i)!}{3!i!} = \frac{1}{(3!)^2} \frac{(12-i)(11-i)(...)(2)(1)}{(9-i)(8-i)(...)(2)(1)}\frac{(3+i)(2+i)(1+i)(i)(...)(2)(1)}{(i)(i-1)(...)(2)(1)}=\frac{1}{36}(12-i)(11-i)(10-i)(i+1)(i+2)(i+3)=\frac{1}{36}(-i^6+27i^5-175i^4-495i^3+4136i^2+12348i+7920)$$

Now : 
$$\sum_{i=0}^n i^6=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^4+6n^3-3n+1)}{42}$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^n i^5=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2(2n^2+2n-1)}{12}$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^n i^4=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)}{30}$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^n i^3=(\Sigma_{i=0}^n i)^2$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^n i^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

So :
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} {12-i\choose3}{3+i\choose3} = \frac{1}{252}(n+1)(-n^6+29n^5-183n^4-1217n^3+8728n^2+48084n+55440)$$

Here, with 9 :
$$\sum_{i=0}^{9} {12-i\choose3}{3+i\choose3} = \frac{1}{252}(10)(-531441+1712421-1200663-887193+706968+432756+55440)=\frac{10}{252}288288=11440$$

---

Or, it can be factored a bit more : 
$$\frac{1}{252}(n+1)(-n^6+29n^5-183n^4-1217n^3+8728n^2+48084n+55440)=\frac{1}{252}(15-n)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)(n+1)(n^2-23n+154)$$
which give you again, with 9 : $$\frac{1}{252}(6)(10)(11)(12)(13)(81-207+154)=\frac{1}{21}(6)(10)(11)(13)(28)=\frac{2}{7}(10)(11)(13)(28)=11440$$

Comment: Hmm, I have thought of just expanding it out. Is there a way without expanding it? I mean without going to $n^6$.

Comment: @user2770287 : I doubt so : I don't see any other reduction you could do here on the binomial coefficients there..

Comment: That is a *very* long road!

Answer (score 2):

$$ \sum_{n\geq 3}\binom{n}{3}x^n = \frac{x^3}{(1-x)^4}\tag{1}$$
hence your sum, read as a convolution, is just the coefficient of $x^{15}$ in the square of $(1)$, i.e.:

$$ [x^{15}]\frac{x^6}{(1-x)^8}=[x^{15}]\sum_{n\geq 7}\binom{n}{7}x^{n-1}=\color{red}{\binom{16}{7}}=11440.\tag{2} $$

Comment: Well actually looks like you can do much better indeed :D

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=0}^9\binom {12-i}3\binom {3+i}3
&=\sum_{i=0}^9\binom {12-i}{9-i}\binom {3+i}{i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^9(-1)^{9-i}\binom {-3-1}{9-i}(-1)^{i}\binom {-3-1}{i}
\qquad&\text{(upper negation)}&\\
&=-\sum_{i=0}^9\binom {-4}{9-i}\binom {-4}i\\
&=-\binom{-8}9\qquad&\text{(Vandermonde)}\\
&=-(-1)^9\binom{17-1}9\qquad&\text{(upper negation)}\\
&=\binom{16}9=\binom {16}7=11440\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$